# My Java EE Eclipse doesn't recognize Java EE libraries

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I am using Java EE Eclipse and I have also installed the Java EE JDK, but still in my servlet while importing `javax.servlet.*`, Eclipse doesn't recognize it.

What do you think might be wrong?

Comment: The first thing people need to know, is your project an Eclipse project or a Maven project? If you're not sure how to tell, is there a "pom.xml" file in the root of your project?

Comment: I have created a dynamic web project..

Comment: And you created the servlet using "New-->Web-->Servlet", I presume?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer yet--just need the bigger format.

Please verify the following things in your project properties (right-click on the project, then Properties from the context menu):

- Java Build Path-->Libraries

  - Verify that "Apache Tomcat 7.0" is present in the list.
  - Expand the Tomcat node and verify there are a bunch of jar files there, and none have red badges on them.
- Project Facets

  - Verify "Dynamic Web Module", "Java", and "JavaScript" are checked.
- Targeted Runtimes

  - Verify "Apache Tomcat 7.0" is checked.

Also verify these things under Preferences:

- Server-->Runtime Environments

  - Verify Apache Tomcat 7.0 is listed (it should be if above is correct).
  - Select the Tomcat item and click the Edit button. Verify the path to you Tomcat install is correct. While you're here, you may as well verify the JRE is correct.

Comment: @user3552862: No problem! What part was the issue?

Comment: In the Libraries list, Apache Tomcat was not present. Also in Targeted Runtimes, Apache Tomcat 7.0 was not checked! :)

Comment: I have a question, do u know how can I set the properties you said for all projects and not only the one I am working with?

Comment: Using Eclipse-style projects, I'm not aware of any way. But some common properties can be set in Preferences.